# How Can I Read Specific Parts of a File in C?

Tags: c, file, io

I wish to read and write to a `.csv` file using this format: `~83474\t>wed 19 march 2014\n`

When reading, I need to ignore the `~`, the tab and the `>`. They are just there to remind my program of what the values that follow are used for. So far I figured out how to write to file using that format, however, I do not know how to read from the file either. I wish to store the numbers after the `~` as an integer value and the characters after the `>` as a string. How can I read those two values from every line in the file if each line has the format stated above?

Comment: Do you know about `scanf` and related functions?

Comment: I know about scanf. Heard about fscanf but I dont understand how it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the whole line as a string using fgets and process it.

Comment: How do I use fgets? How can I process it? Please explain, I'm not well acquainted with C.

Comment: You need to read about fgets & strtod, then.   
http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets   
http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod   

You can use fgets to read from the file, then use strtod to extract the integer out of it. The endptr argument in strtod will get you the start index of the remaining string which you can then copy into a string